# To get only first record from the group of employee

Tags: mysql, t-sql

I have follwing data:

```
emp_no  emp_name    login   level   HOD_NAME    Assigend_IP LoggedIn_IP Attendece_Location  Shift_Timing
E31446  Amit Singh  09:39   Direct  P00212  172.29.23.53    172.29.23.53    CSO-Ackruti Star-6F 09:30-18:30
E31446  Amit Singh  09:39   Direct  P00212  172.29.23.53    172.29.23.53    CSO-Ackruti Star-6F 09:30-18:30
E39787  Anita Haridas Shenoy    09:41   Indirect    E31446  172.29.24.38    172.29.23.55    CSO-Ackruti Star-6F 09:30-18:30
E39787  Anita Haridas Shenoy    09:41   Indirect    E31446  172.29.24.38    172.29.24.38    CSO-Ackruti Star-6F 09:30-18:30
E39787  Anita Haridas Shenoy    09:41   Indirect    E31446  172.29.24.38    172.29.23.55    CSO-Ackruti Star-6F 09:30-18:30
E39787  Anita Haridas Shenoy    09:41   Indirect    E31446  172.29.24.38    172.29.24.38    CSO-Ackruti Star-6F 09:30-18:30
E37731  Ramesh Shukla   09:40   Indirect    E31446  172.29.23.43    172.29.23.43    CSO-Ackruti Star-6F 09:30-18:30
E37731  Ramesh Shukla   09:40   Indirect    E31446  172.29.23.43    172.29.23.55    CSO-Ackruti Star-6F 09:30-18:30
E33995  Rakesh Sharma   08:21   Direct  P00212  172.29.23.17    172.29.23.17    CSO-Ackruti Star-6F 09:30-18:30
E43130  Lubna Shaikh    09:37   Indirect    E33995  172.29.23.54    172.29.23.54    CSO-Ackruti Star-6F 09:30-18:30
E43130  Lubna Shaikh    09:37   Indirect    E33995  172.29.23.54    172.29.23.58    CSO-Ackruti Star-6F 09:30-18:30
E43130  Lubna Shaikh    09:37   Indirect    E33995  172.29.23.54    172.29.23.54    CSO-Ackruti Star-6F 09:30-18:30
E43130  Lubna Shaikh    09:37   Indirect    E33995  172.29.23.54    172.29.23.58    CSO-Ackruti Star-6F 09:30-18:30
E43455  Manish Shukla       Indirect    E33995  172.29.23.45    172.29.23.45    CSO-Ackruti Star-6F 09:30-18:30
E44920  Shweta Salve    09:18   Indirect    E33995  172.29.23.55    172.29.23.55    CSO-Ackruti Star-6F 09:30-18:30
```

Now i want to filter this data in such manner, so that i can get data as following output:

```
emp_no  emp_name    login   level   HOD_NAME    Assigend_IP LoggedIn_IP Attendece_Location  Shift_Timing
E31446  Amit Singh  9:39    Direct  P00212  172.29.23.53    172.29.23.53    CSO-Ackruti Star-6F 09:30-18:30
E39787  Anita Haridas Shenoy    9:41    Indirect    E31446  172.29.24.38    172.29.23.55    CSO-Ackruti Star-6F 09:30-18:30
E37731  Ramesh Shukla   9:40    Indirect    E31446  172.29.23.43    172.29.23.43    CSO-Ackruti Star-6F 09:30-18:30
E33995  Rakesh Sharma   8:21    Direct  P00212  172.29.23.17    172.29.23.17    CSO-Ackruti Star-6F 09:30-18:30
E43130  Lubna Shaikh    9:37    Indirect    E33995  172.29.23.54    172.29.23.54    CSO-Ackruti Star-6F 09:30-18:30
E43455  Manish Shukla       Indirect    E33995  172.29.23.45    172.29.23.45    CSO-Ackruti Star-6F 09:30-18:30
E44920  Shweta Salve    9:18    Indirect    E33995  172.29.23.55    172.29.23.55    CSO-Ackruti Star-6F 09:30-18:30
```

The output should contain only first record of each employee..
How can i write query for this ?

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: @shweta : How do you decide which row is first ?

Comment: @ravi singh :in each group of employee first row is first login punch of employee so its depends on logintime.

Comment: @shweta : Here login time is duplicate. Then what other criteria do you use ?

Comment: You should try ORDER BY Login ASC  and group by emp_no. Hope it will help you.

Comment: MySQL and T-SQL are two different things; which one do you want, or do you want both?

Comment: The use cases haven't been well enough defined.   In the data examples provided, the same users have logged in at precisely the same time from multiple locations:   so the "first" login is not determinable.   If you want to return a single record per user, you'll have to specify further rules to determine the "first" login when there is more than one record for that user with the same login time.

Comment: +1 Not very difficult for solving but fundamental issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is full working example using [ROW_NUMBER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function. The key part is the following row:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY [emp_no] ORDER BY [emp_no] )
```

It means that "ID" number will be generated for each row, grouping the rows by [emp_no] column. If you need other criteria for sort, you can use any one of the columns.

This is the whole code:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
GO

    DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
    (
         [emp_no] VARCHAR(6)
        ,[emp_name] NVARCHAR(24)
        ,[login] VARCHAR(6)
        ,[level] NVARCHAR(25)
        ,[HOD_NAME] NVARCHAR(24)
        ,[Assigend_IP ] NVARCHAR(64)
        ,[LoggedIn_IP ] NVARCHAR(64)
        ,[Attendece_Location] NVARCHAR(64)
        ,[Shift_Timing] NVARCHAR(64)
    ) 

    INSERT INTO @DataSource
    VALUES   ('E31446','Amit Singh','09:39',' Direct','P00212','172.29.23.53','172.29.23.53','CSO-Ackruti Star-6F','09:30-18:30')
            ,('E31446','Amit Singh','09:39',' Direct','P00212','172.29.23.53','172.29.23.53','CSO-Ackruti Star-6F','09:30-18:30')
            ,('E39787','Anita Haridas Shenoy','09:41',' Indirect','E31446','172.29.24.38','172.29.23.55','CSO-Ackruti Star-6F','09:30-18:30')
            ,('E39787','Anita Haridas Shenoy','09:41',' Indirect','E31446','172.29.24.38','172.29.24.38','CSO-Ackruti Star-6F','09:30-18:30')
            ,('E39787','Anita Haridas Shenoy','09:41',' Indirect','E31446','172.29.24.38','172.29.23.55','CSO-Ackruti Star-6F','09:30-18:30')
            ,('E39787','Anita Haridas Shenoy','09:41',' Indirect','E31446','172.29.24.38','172.29.24.38','CSO-Ackruti Star-6F','09:30-18:30')
            ,('E37731','Ramesh Shukla',' 09:40',' Indirect','E31446','172.29.23.43','172.29.23.43','CSO-Ackruti Star-6F','09:30-18:30')
            ,('E37731','Ramesh Shukla',' 09:40',' Indirect','E31446','172.29.23.43','172.29.23.55','CSO-Ackruti Star-6F','09:30-18:30')
            ,('E33995','Rakesh Sharma',' 08:21',' Direct','P00212','172.29.23.17','172.29.23.17','CSO-Ackruti Star-6F','09:30-18:30')
            ,('E43130','Lubna Shaikh','09:37',' Indirect','E33995','172.29.23.54','172.29.23.54','CSO-Ackruti Star-6F','09:30-18:30')
            ,('E43130','Lubna Shaikh','09:37',' Indirect','E33995','172.29.23.54','172.29.23.58','CSO-Ackruti Star-6F','09:30-18:30')
            ,('E43130','Lubna Shaikh','09:37',' Indirect','E33995','172.29.23.54','172.29.23.54','CSO-Ackruti Star-6F','09:30-18:30')
            ,('E43130','Lubna Shaikh','09:37',' Indirect','E33995','172.29.23.54','172.29.23.58','CSO-Ackruti Star-6F','09:30-18:30')
            ,('E43455','Manish Shukla','',' Indirect','E33995','172.29.23.45','172.29.23.45','CSO-Ackruti Star-6F','09:30-18:30')
            ,('E44920','Shweta Salve','09:18',' Indirect','E33995','172.29.23.55','172.29.23.55','CSO-Ackruti Star-6F','09:30-18:30')

    ;WITH DataSource AS
    (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY [emp_no] ORDER BY [emp_no] ) AS [RecordNumber]
              ,[emp_no] 
              ,[emp_name] 
              ,[login] 
              ,[level] 
              ,[HOD_NAME] 
              ,[Assigend_IP ] 
              ,[LoggedIn_IP ] 
              ,[Attendece_Location] 
              ,[Shift_Timing] 
        FROM @DataSource
    )
    SELECT [emp_no] 
          ,[emp_name] 
          ,[login] 
          ,[level] 
          ,[HOD_NAME] 
          ,[Assigend_IP ] 
          ,[LoggedIn_IP ] 
          ,[Attendece_Location] 
          ,[Shift_Timing] 
    FROM DataSource
    WHERE [RecordNumber] = 1

SET NOCOUNT OFF
GO
```

And this is the output:

[image]

Comment: For the record, this doesn't remotely do what the OP asked.  It *does* pick only one of each user, but completely ignores the login time with the result.  Try mixing up the times in the sample data and watch what happens:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/18282

Comment: What happens? And as I said - "If you need other criteria for sort, you can use any one of the columns."

Answer (score 2):

```
select 
emp_no,emp_name,login,level,
HOD_NAME,Assigend_IP,min(LoggedIn_IP),
Attendece_Location,Shift_Timing
from table_name
group by 
emp_no,emp_name,login,level,
HOD_NAME,Assigend_IP,
Attendece_Location,Shift_Timing
```

Comment: That would provide the lowest-numbered IP address, but not the first login.

Comment: @shweta Exact the **[same output](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/867d2/2)** which you needed.

Comment: @Luv i got the out put from your query ..but this query will return min of logged in Ip?? it may create problem in future

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT * 
   FROM EmployeeLog LOG
        INNER JOIN
        (
           SELECT emp_name, 
                  MAX(login) AS last_login
            FROM EmployeeLog
                 GROUP BY emp_name
        ) LATEST
           ON LOG.emp_name = LATEST.emp_name
           AND LOG.login = LATEST.last_login
```

This will give the the *latest* login record for each employee, which is what I think you're after.

If you're after the *earliest* login, change the `MAX()` in the subquery to `MIN()`.

Comment: @Luv    Your data has each user logging in simultaneously from three or four different places.  Not so sure that's what the OP was asking about... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query for getting only one record from duplicate records,

```
 SELECT * ,count(*) as cnt,emp_name FROM `emp`
 group by emp_name
```